# Iinsert/Replace data in SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, insert, replace

Why can't I update data to SQLite eventhought it print "yes yes", please help, here my code, it called from viewdidload:

```
    -(void)updateData{

    CryptTestAppDelegate *delegate=(CryptTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;


    NSString *dd = @"testing";

    const char *sql = "Update ProvPuzz set desc2=?";


    sqlite3_prepare_v2(delegate.db, sql, 1, &stmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [dd UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(sqlite3_step(stmt)){

        NSLog(@"yes yes");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"no  no");
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(delegate.db);  



}
```

It seems to pass every step, but my data not change at all. Any help please...
How should I call/code to be able to insert/replace these record in SQLite?

Comment: I'm sure you're trying to write to the database file which is in your app's main bundle. You can't write to the main bundle.

Comment: So where can I put the database then (what location?)?

Comment: Into the Documents directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSString *UpdateSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update ProvPuzz set desc2 = something"];
const char *sqlStatement = [UpdateSql UTF8String];  
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(filesDB, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) 
        {
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);   

        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);   
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    sqlite3_close(filesDB);
```

and also check you db connection opened properly or not

Comment: It runs without any problem, but DB nothing change. Any suggestion about DB location that can not stand in the same App Folder?

Comment: I know now, actually the data is changed, but just my fault, that did not check the data with the real DB that stayed at the Simulator folder. Thanks